# Python Numpy error : setting an array element with a sequence

Tags: python, numpy

I'm quite new to Python and Numpy, so I apologize if I'm missing something obvious here.

I have a function that solves a system of 2 differential equations :

```
import numpy as np
import numpy.linalg as la

def solve_ode(x0, a0, beta, t):
    At = np.array([[0.23*t, (-10**5)*t], [0, -beta*t]], dtype=np.float32)

    # get eigenvalues and eigenvectors
    evals, V = la.eig(At)
    Vi = la.inv(V)

    # get e^At coeff
    eAt = V @ np.exp(evals) @ Vi

    xt = eAt*x0
    return xt
```

However, running it with this code :

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# initial values
x0 = 10**6
a0 = 2.5
beta = 0.05

t = np.linspace(0, 3600, 360)

plt.semilogy(t, solve_ode(x0, a0, beta, t))
```

... throws this error :

```
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

At this line :

```
At = np.array([[0.23*t, (-10**5)*t], [0, -beta*t]], dtype=np.float32)
```

Note that `t` and `beta` are supposed to be `floats`. I think Python might not be able to infer this but I don't know how I could do this...

Thx in advance for your help.

Comment: If **t** is a scalar **At** becomes a 2x2 array. Now the problem is that Numpy doesn't know what to do when you make **t** a list of numbers. It can't fill the cells with arrays. That why you get the Value Error.

Since I'm not a Physics/Maths major I'm not sure how the appropriate solution would look like. Is the idea to run solve_ode() for each value of **t**? Or should **At** grow in a specific manner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are supplying `t` as a numpy array of shape 360 from linspace and not simply a float. The resulting `At` numpy array you are trying to create is then ill formed as all columns must be the same length. In python there is an important difference between lists and numpy arrays. For example, you could do what you have here as a list of lists, e.g.

```
At = [[0.23*t, (-10**5)*t], [0, -beta*t]]
```

with dimensions [[360 x 360] x [1 x 360]].

Alternatively, if all elements of At are the length of `t` the array would work,

```
At = np.array([[0.23*t, (-10**5)*t], [t, -beta*t]], dtype=np.float32)
```

with shape [2, 2, 360].

Comment: Thank you very much! For some stupid reason, I assumed scipy would iterate over t and pass to my function every single value contained in the linspace. I understand now, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

When you give a `list` or a `list` of `list`s, or in this case, a `list` of `list` of `lists`s, all of them should have the same length, so that `numpy` can automatically infer the dimensions (shape) of the resulting matrix.

In your example, it's all correctly put, except the part you put `0` as a *column* I guess. Not sure what to call it though, cause your expected output is a cube I suppose.

You can fix it by giving the correct number of zeros as bellow:

```
At = np.array([[0.23*t, (-10**5)*t], [np.zeros(len(t)), -beta*t]], dtype=np.float32)
```

But check the `.shape` of the resulting array, and make sure it's what you want.

Answer (score 0):

As others note the problem is the `0` in the inner list.  It doesn't match the `360` length arrays generated by the other expressions.  `np.array` can make an object dtype array from that (2x2), but can't make a float one.

```
At = np.array([[0.23*t, (-10**5)*t], [0*t, -beta*t]])
```

produces a (2,2,360) array. But I suspect the rest of that function is built around the assumption that `At` is (2,2) - a 2d square array with `eig`, `inv` etc.

What is the return `xt` supposed to be?

Does this work?

```
S = np.array([solve_ode(x0, a0, beta, i) for i in t])
```

giving a 1d array with the same number of values as in `t`?

I'm not suggesting this is the fastest way of solving the problem, but it's the simplest, especially if you are only generating 360 values.